# Do the enlightened not experience the results of their past karma?

Tags: karma, sutras, nirvana, buddha

Can buddha attain Nibbana without Devadatta's throwing a rock and hurting Buddha's foot?

I read somewhere that buddha redeem his past karma by getting hit from that stone hence my question

I am sorry for my bad english
Metta

UPDATED:

But there were present karmas that even buddha needs to undergo do you assert that the enlighten one don't need to undergo present karma at all?

Comment: I think it would encourage more people to take an interest if there were more details in the body of the question; perhaps the source from whence the question arose.

Comment: The Buddha was injured by Devadatta AFTER he became enlightened. So, how is it logical to ask if without that event, could the Buddha have become enlightened?

Comment: But there were present karmas that even buddha needs to undergo
 do you assert that the enlighten one don't need to undergo present karma at all ?